# Calculating point-wise mutual information (PMI) score for n-grams in Python

Tags: python, n-gram

I have a large corpus of n-grams and several external n-grams. I want to calculate the PMI score of each external n-gram based on this corpus (the counts).

Are there any tools to do this or can someone provide me with a piece of code in Python that can do this?

The problem is that my n-grams are 2-grams, 3-grams, 4-grams, and 5-grams. So calculating probabilities for 3-grams and more are really time-consuming.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I'm understanding your problem correctly, you want to compute things like log { P("x1 x2 x3 x4 x5") / P("x1") P("x2") ... P("x5") } where P measures the probability that any given 5-gram or 1-gram is a given thing (and is basically a ratio of counts, perhaps with Laplace-style offsets). So, make a single pass through your corpus and store counts of (1) each 1-gram, (2) each n-gram (use a dict for the latter), and then for each external n-gram you do a few dict lookups, a bit of arithmetic, and you're done. One pass through the corpus at the start, then a fixed amount of work per external n-gram.

(Note: Actually I'm not sure how one defines PMI for more than two random variables; perhaps it's something like log P(a)P(b)P(c)P(abc) / P(ab)P(bc)P(a_c). But if it's anything at all along those lines, you can do it the same way: iterate through your corpus counting lots of things, and then all the probabilities you need are simply ratios of the counts, perhaps with Laplace-ish corrections.)

If your corpus is so big that you can't fit the n-gram dict in memory, then divide it into kinda-memory-sized chunks, compute n-gram dicts for each chunk and store them on disc in a form that lets you get at any given n-gram's entry reasonably efficiently; then, for each extern n-gram, go through the chunks and add up the counts.

What form? Up to you. One simple option: in lexicographic order of the n-gram (note: if you're working with words rather than letters, you may want to begin by turning words into numbers; you'll want a single preliminary pass over your corpus to do this); then finding the n-gram you want is a binary search or something of the kind, which with chunks 1GB in size would mean somewhere on the order of 15-20 seeks per chunk; you could add some extra indexing to reduce this. Or: use a hash table on disc, with Berkeley DB or something; in that case you can forgo the chunking. Or, if the alphabet is small (e.g., these are letter n-grams rather than word n-grams and you're processing plain English text), just store them in a big array, with direct lookup -- but in that case, you can probably fit the whole thing in memory anyway.